# Unable to place order for a product, using the same product Id in Rest Assured

Tags: java, automation, rest-assured, pojo

I am trying to do one Rest Assured API E2E flow on an E-commerce web site which includes Logging in, adding a product and then creating an order for that product, however I am unable to execute the last step of actually creating an order for that specific product - It complains of 'Wrong Product Id".

This is the code of my main class

```java
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import pojo.EcommerceLoginRequest;
import pojo.EcommerceLoginResponse;
import pojo.EcommerceOrderDetail;
import pojo.EcommerceOrders;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ECommerceAPITest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    //Login
        
     RequestSpecification req = new RequestSpecBuilder().setBaseUri("https://rahulshettyacademy.com").setContentType(ContentType.JSON).build();
     
     EcommerceLoginRequest loginRequest = new EcommerceLoginRequest();
     loginRequest.setUserEmail("imtiyaz_@hotmail.co.uk");
     loginRequest.setUserPassword("786Immy110.1");
     
     
    RequestSpecification reqLogin = given().log().all().spec(req).body(loginRequest); 
    EcommerceLoginResponse loginResponse = reqLogin.when().post("/api/ecom/auth/login").then().log().all().extract().response().as(EcommerceLoginResponse.class);
     
    
    
    System.out.println(loginResponse.getToken());
    String token = loginResponse.getToken();
    System.out.println(loginResponse.getuserId());
    String userId = loginResponse.getuserId();
    
    
    //Add Product

    RequestSpecification addProductBaseReq = new RequestSpecBuilder().setBaseUri("https://rahulshettyacademy.com")
    .addHeader("authorization", token)
    .build();
    
    RequestSpecification reqAddProduct = given().log().all().spec(addProductBaseReq).param("productName", "screenshot")
    .param("productAddedBy", userId).param("productCategory", "fashion")
    .param("productSubCategory", "shirts").param("productPrice", "11500")
    .param("productDescription", "Lenova").param("productFor", "men")
    .multiPart("productImage", new File("/Users/imtiyaz/Desktop/Screenshot 2023-08-25 at 00.22.26.png")); //multiPart is used when sending multimedia - files, images, video etc.
    
    String addProductResponse = reqAddProduct.when().post("/api/ecom/product/add-product")
    .then().log().all().extract().response().asString();
    
    JsonPath js = new JsonPath (addProductResponse);
    String productId = js.get("productId");
    
    
    
    //Create order for the Added Product
    
    RequestSpecification createOrderBaseReq = new RequestSpecBuilder().setBaseUri("https://rahulshettyacademy.com")
            .addHeader("authorization", token).setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .build();
    
    EcommerceOrderDetail orderDetail = new EcommerceOrderDetail();
    orderDetail.setCountry("India");
    orderDetail.setProductOrderId(productId);
    
    List<EcommerceOrderDetail>orderDetailList = new ArrayList<EcommerceOrderDetail>(); 
    orderDetailList.add(orderDetail);
    
    EcommerceOrders orders =  new EcommerceOrders();
    orders.setOrders(orderDetailList);
    
    
RequestSpecification createOrderReq = given().log().all().spec(createOrderBaseReq).body(orders);
String responseAddOrder = createOrderReq.when().post("/api/ecom/order/create-order").then().log().all().extract().response().asString(); 
System.out.println(responseAddOrder);
    
    
    
    }

}
```

As you can see in the line where I've put 'orderDetail.setProductOrderId(productId);' I am using the same productId variable when putting that as a String object in previous steps.

Below is the code for EcommerceOrderDetail.java class (pojo class):

```
package pojo;

public class EcommerceOrderDetail {
    
    String country;
    String productOrderId;
    
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getProductOrderId() {
        return productOrderId;
    }
    public void setProductOrderId(String productOrderId) {
        this.productOrderId = productOrderId;
    }
    

}
```

Code for 'EcommerceOrders.java' class:

```
package pojo;

import java.util.List;

public class EcommerceOrders {
    
    private List<EcommerceOrderDetail> orders; //The value of this 'orders' is nothing but list because it is an array inside 'orders' and in that array there is the 'Country' and 'productOrderId'

    public List<EcommerceOrderDetail> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<EcommerceOrderDetail> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
    
    

}
```